# How to read an integer from a buffer in Rust 1.0?

Tags: io, rust

The API for reading scalar values seems to have been removed from the `Cursor` and `Reader` io traits. Is there a standard library replacement for these or do I have to write my own?

For example, it used to be possible to write:

```
let magic = try!(reader.read_be_u16());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality is not in the standard library any more, but there are other libraries providing it.
[byteorder](https://github.com/BurntSushi/byteorder) is a popular one.